# What does "where T" in julia do without any specification after T?

Tags: julia

I'm new to julia and I have not been able to find an explanation of `where` that fully makes sense to me.
So I understand that for example
`function f(x::T, y::T) where {T<:Number} = true` is requiring that both the x and y parameters be numeric types of some sort.

But then there are other functions that will look like `function f(X::AbstractMatrix{T}) where T` without any specification of what T is supposed to be. Can someone explain what that is doing and when I would want to use this syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`where T` without anything else is just `where {T<:Any}` in other words, it's true for all `T`, but Julia needs you to write something so that `T is defined.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So then what is the difference between ```function f(x::AbstractMatrix)``` and ```function f(x::AbstractMatrix{T}) where T``` ?

Comment: You have access to `T` inside the function body of the latter definition.  That's it.

Comment: the other - tiny - difference is that Julia will ignore `@nospecialize` for the definition using the `where T` approach.

Answer (score 4):

Oscar's answer is correct, but to answer your second question,

> When I would want to use this syntax?

like mbauman suggested in the comments, a typical use for this syntax is when you want to use the type in the body of the function. Maybe the example [in the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Parametric-Methods) helps:

```
julia> mytypeof(x::T) where {T} = T
mytypeof (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mytypeof(1)
Int64

julia> mytypeof(1.0)
Float64
```